# the set $\{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N} | \text{$f$ is continous}\}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, set-theory

Prove or disprove:

1- the set $\{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N} | \text{$f$ is continuous}\}$ is countable.

2-the set $\{f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} | \text{$f$ is continuous}\}$ is countable.

I think 2 is wrong because for every irrational number $\alpha$ the set of constant functions $f(x)=\alpha$ is uncountable.

Comment: Those are called *constant* functions, not fixed functions, and it would be simpler to consider all of them, not only the irrational ones. You're right, $2$ is false. What have you tried for $1$?

Comment: @jjagmath . I think 1 is true. Because for every element in domain we have countable choices but uncountable union of countable set is not in general countable.

Comment: What topology on $\Bbb N$ are you using?

Comment: @jjagmath . Also every arbitrary function to $\mathbb N $ is continous .

Comment: @jjagmath . Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{N}  $ is equivalent to discrate topology.

Comment: Since $\mathbb N$ is discrete and $\mathbb R$ is connected, the only continuous functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb N$ are the constant functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean every function to $\mathbb{N}$, as you claimed in comment, then 1 is certainly not true, since the family $\left\{\chi_a\right\}_{a\in\mathbb{R}}$, where $\chi _a\left ( a \right ) =1$ and $\chi _a\left ( x \right ) =0$ for $x\neq a$ is uncoutable.

But if you mean continuous functions, then they are exactly the constant functions, we shall prove this.

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a continuous function, then if the range of $f$ contains more than one point, then take $x\in \mathrm{Im}f$ and then $f^{-1}(x)$ and $f^{-1}(\mathrm{Im}f\setminus \left\{x\right\})$ are disjoint non-void opens sets whose union is $\mathbb{R}$. But $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $f^{-1}\left(\{x\}\right)$ an open set ?

Comment: @Angelo Since $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{N}$ has got the discrete topology.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you, but why cannot $\mathbb N$ have another topology apart from the discrete one ?